# How to view pdf file that is saved in DB

Tags: vb.net, pdf

This for download but I want only to display. Please help me

```
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
                fs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
                'Set image variable value using memory stream. 
                fs.Flush()
                fs.Close()
            End Using


            ShellEx(Me.Handle, "Open", sFileName, "", "", 10)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic].  Please retag.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your binary object [pdf file] from DB, write it to disk

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\xxx\file.pdf", binaryData)
```

and then, start process with default program assigned to open pdf files

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\xxx\file.pdf")
```